# Ubuntu 16.04 saying battery discharging even after plugged in charger

Tags: laptop, power-management, battery

I have plugged in charger and run following command:

```
cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status
```

It says `discharging` in both cases plugged in or plugged out. Even battery icon indicator is not changing when connected to charger.

I tried many existing solution but not working for me.
Where as in case of Windows the charging working fine and battery getting charge properly.

Laptop details:

- Lenovo L450
- i7 Processor
- 8 GB Ram